# The security of blind RSA signatures with modular exponentiation as padding

Tags: rsa, provable-security, modular-arithmetic, blind-signature

It is known that (blind) RSA signature implementations should apply some sort of padding to messages before signing or blinding them. Does blind RSA signature with modular exponentiation as a padding scheme, ie. $H(m)=g^m \mod N$ for some generator $g$, ***remain secure***? I can restrict the message space to be $\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{N}$.

My motivation to do this is to preserve some homomorphicity of messages as later I would like to prove some relations between blinded messages. Instead if I would use FDH (full domain hash), then I would lose homomorphic properties of (blinded) messages and could not prove anymore relations between the underlying messages.

A counter-example would be blind BLS, which is completely broken with modular exponentiation as a hash function. Is there any similarly obvious negative indication against applying modular exponentiation as padding/hashing in case of blind RSA?

Comment: Could you please elaborate the blind signature you propose?

Comment: So you mean a cryptographically secure hash directly converted to a unsigned number? That does sound a bit dangerous to me. Wouldn't that be as secure as any RSA with just a hash?

Comment: Exactly @MaartenBodewes! So essentially the construction would be the same as textbook blind RSA just replacing $m$ with $g^m \mod N$. That's my hope as well, that it remains secure also with the modular exponentiation hash. But given the counter-example of BLS, I became a little bit cautious!